# How to solve unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple' because of trying to return 2 values with lambda?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to return 2 values with lambda but I ended up getting this error :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

And this is the code which I got the error :

```
def mean(n):
    return sum(n)/len(n) 

dataset = [
    {"name": "John",  "distance": 5602,  "max-speed": 504},
    {"name": "Mike",  "distance": 5242,  "max-speed": 622},
    {"name": "Chad",  "distance": 4825,  "max-speed": 453},
    {"name": "Phil",  "distance": 611,   "max-speed": 500},
    {"name": "Tyler", "distance": 5436,  "max-speed": 909}
]

mean(list(map(lambda x : (x["distance"], x["max-speed"]), dataset)))
```

If it was only x["distance"] or x["max-speed"], it would return the value that I want. I want the output to be

> mean of distance
>
> mean of max-speed

Thanks in advances.

Comment: You're calling `mean` on a list of tuples. What do you want the result to be?

Comment: I want the result to be :
mean of distance and mean of max-speed @TannerSwett

Comment: Also I could separate each function one by one to make it works. But I just want to know if it could work with one liner of function~

Comment: It can indeed work, if you write a new version of `mean` that takes a list of N-length tuples and returns an N-length list (or tuple) of their means.

Comment: Gotcha, I solve it finally, thanks @TomDalton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I could solve it with this mean function

```
def mean(arr):
    n = float(len(arr))
    return tuple(sum(x[i] for x in arr)/n for i in range (len(arr[0])))

mean(tuple(map(lambda x : (x["distance"],x["max-speed"]),dataset)))
```

output :

```
(4343.2, 597.6)
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

it is ?

```
def mean(n):
    return (sum([x for x,y in n]) / len(n),
            sum([y for x,y in n]) / len(l))
```

output:

```
(4343.2, 597.6)
```

Comment: There is one problem. If I have 3 arguments, the mean won't work and I should add the new one.  But anyways it's a great alternative thou. Thank you.